# pandas plugin for python in a canopy environment not sorting?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've been working on this for a few hours and am giving up at this point. I have a scientific tool that is slightly glitching and creating a .csv database with datapoints out of order, i.e.

```
Test_ID Data_Point  Test_Time   Step_Time etc...

1   1439    1441.044976 1328.572329
1   1440    1442.046983 1329.574335
1   1121    1122.423305 1009.950658
1   1122    1123.424295 1010.951648
```

Note how the data skips from 1440 back to 1121. if you backed tracked in the .csv file you'd find a section of about 40 rows, after 1120, missing.  This is a large data file of about 125k rows.

I'm using python in the canopy environment with pandas installed. I'm trying to sort the database on the Data_Point (as I thought it'd be the easiest, you could do it based on test or step time) column keeping the rows intact. Here is the code I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from pylab import plt, plot, legend, show

df = pd.read_csv("C:\ArbinData\PanCell3_Cycling_0-30.csv")
df2 = df.sort_values('Data_Point',  ascending = 0)

for x in range(1, len(df2['Data_Point']):
    #Do science.
```

Thanks for any help, I'm out of energy on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) wrongly. The parameters of the argument `ascending` have to be boolean`(True/False)` and not binary`(1/0)` values.

It should be:

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['Data_Point'], ascending=False)
```

This sorts the values in descending order.

---

Newer syntax starting from `v0.17.0` supports the usage of integers `1/0` to depict the boolean `True/False` values respectively.

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['Data_Point'], ascending=0)
```

You can even pass a `list` of elements to the `ascending` keyword argument whose length corresponds to the number of items passed to the `by` keyword argument.